# My C function in Bison?

Tags: c, bison

I have a C function that I would like to use in my .y bison file. How do I do that? Where do I put the code for my function?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In your .y file you can do something like:

```
%{
#include "types.h"
#include "interface.h"
void doStuff(void);    
%}
```

Either `#include`ing a header file or declaring it right there.

This means that if interface.h declared a `add_colour` and `add_colourd` function you could do something like this later on:

```
Colour:
          ColourSpace { add_colour($1); }
        | STAR ColourSpace { add_colourd($2); }
```

calling them from witin your generated code.

If you wanted to implement them in that generated code to you could use `%%` at the end of the file and do something like:

```
%%
void doStuff() {
  // Do some stuff!
}
```

So you can write "plain old C" inside your .y file too.